# Is there a useable command line profiling tool on OS X?

Tags: macos

I wanna use something like gprof to profile C/C++ programs on command line. But unfortunately gprof doesn't work on OS X for some reason (that's a known issue).

When I search this topic on internet, almost everyone recommends Instruments.app. As my workflow is entirely in command-line environment, I really don't want to switch to GUI just for some profiling.

So is there currently a usable alternative to gprof on OS X, which is purely command line based?

**Edit**: More specifically, I want to use the tool to analyze the runtime of each function in my program, to find out the hotspots.

Answer (score 3):

There's a command line tool component of Instruments: the [`instruments`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html) command. You typically will want to use Instruments.app to view the resulting trace, though.

Besides that, there are lots of different tools. There's `sample` for simple time profiling. There's `spindump`. There's DTrace and a whole suite of ready-made DTrace-based tools. (See `man -k dtrace` for a list.)

You'll need to be more specific about what exactly you're hoping to investigate about your programs to a get a more specific suggestion.

Comment: This answer could be improved by including a cut-and-pasteable *example* of how to use each of these tools on the command line. The `instruments` man page is spectacularly awful.

Comment: @Quuxplusone that's what people should expect from osx platform